# Does $n!$ divide $ n^n$?

Tags: factorial

Today while I was reading on how to shuffle an array I came across a statement that claims we shall not swap an array entry with the whole array range when shuffling the array otherwise we end up with a biased result. Click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors) for details.

They demonstrated that by saying that $n!$ does not divide $n^n$ because $(n-1)$ divide $n!$ but at the same time $(n-1)$ does not share any prime factor with $n$, if I understood it right.

However, I did not grasp the "proof" given, so, can you help me figure out how to demonstrate it in a more rigorous approach?

Comment: If $n$ is prime, the factors of $n^n$ are obvious. But what are the factors of $n!$?

Comment: It is rigorous. Suppose that $n-1\gt 1$. Then $n-1$ has a prime divisor $p$. This $p$ does not divide $n$, else it would divide $n-(n-1)$, which is $1$. So $p$ does not divide $n^n$. (if a prime divides a product, it must divide one at least of the terms, this is sometimes called Euclid's Lemma.).

Comment: Well, n is a integer > 0, so it can of course be a prime but we cannot build a proof based on that.

Comment: Andre, if get it right, we just demonstrated that p does not divide n^n. How can that help us demonstrating that n! does not dive n^n ?

Comment: We have $p$ divides $n!$ and therefore if $n!$ divided $n^n$, it would follow that $p$ divides $n^n$. We have shown that if $n-1\gt 1$ this can't happen.

Comment: Now, I get it, thank you Andre. However, the gist of this proof is in demonstrating that p does not divide n. How did you come up with the brilliant conclusion that if p divide (n-1) it cannot divide n, otherwise it would divide n - (n-1) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the comments it is detailed how to find a prime $p$ such that $p \; \mid \; n-1$ but $p \; \nmid \; n^n$.

Suppose it were true now that $(n-1)! \; \mid \; n^n$.
Then we would have
$$
p \mid n -1 \mid (n-1)! \mid n^n
$$
so $p \mid n^n$, which is impossible.

Comment: Thank you Goos for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $4^4 = 2^{8}$, which has no 3 in its prime factorization, while $4! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 = 2^3 \cdot 3$.

Comment: Smaller: $3^3$ vs $3! = 2 \cdot 3$.

Answer (score -2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With Induction, you will use:
$$
{\pars{n + 1}^{n + 1} \over \pars{n + 1}!} = {\pars{n + 1}^{n} \over n!}
={n^{n} \over n!}\,{\pars{n + 1}^{n} \over n^{n}}
={n^{n} \over n!}\
\underbrace{\pars{1 + {1 \over n}}^{n}}
_{\ds{\not\in\ {\mathbb N}_{+}}}
$$
$\imp\quad n!\ \not\vert\ n^{n}$

Comment: Postpones the proof to the step that $(1+1/n)^n$ is not an integer and seems to believe that if $a$ and $b$ are not integers then $ab$ is not an integer.